# How to capture Flash images from Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Is there any way to capture flash images presented in web sites using selenium ide or RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

- Inject action script to flash object to communicate with javascript, then selenium can control them via javascript

  - cons: We must have modification access to flash object to in order to inject action scripts for automation
  - ref:

    - http://www.testinggeek.com/index.php/testing-tools/test-execution/145-flash-object-automation-using-selenium
    - "http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/"
    - "http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/"

- Native Flex automation engine
  e.g. FlexMonkey : Adobe’s record-playback tool for flash
  "http://flexmonkey.gorillalogic.com/gl/stuff.flexmonkey.html"

  - cons: Cannot test embedded flash